# How can we use filter in Apache age for condition?

Tags: postgresql, filter, apache-age, opencypher

In postgreSQL, we can use filter such as-

```html
SELECT column_name,
       SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE year = 2022) AS total_sales_2022,
       SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE year = 2023) AS total_sales_2023
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY column_name;
```

How can we implement this in Apache age? Anyone help me plz.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Doc](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/aggregation.html),

> To calculate aggregated data, Cypher offers aggregation, analogous to SQL’s GROUP BY.

An equivalent cypher query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('sales', $$
MATCH (product) WHERE product.year = 2022 WITH product.name as name, count(*) as c, SUM(product.sales) as 
sales
RETURN name, sales
$$) AS (name agtype, sales agtype);
```

This query will match for the products, filter on the year and apply aggregation using `COUNT` (analogous to `GROUP BY`). Then you can apply `SUM` aggregation function to calculate the total sales for each product.

Comment: It might be worth adding to the answer that you can test for a range of years (as asked in the original question) using something like `WHERE product.year IN [2022,2023]` Also worth noting that you should not need to use `count` to force an aggregation. In Cypher `sum` alone should do that.

Answer (score 0):

In apacheAGE we are not dealing with tables, but with nodes and edges.
Those nodes/edges hold information though their labels and/or properties. For example :

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test_graph', $$
CREATE (u:Person {name: 'John'})
CREATE (v:Person {name: 'Jake'})
CREATE (k:Person {name: 'Alice'})
CREATE (l:Person {name: 'Anna'}) $$)
AS (u agtype);
```

Here we create 4 different nodes with `Person` as the label, and their respective `name` as property. If we want to find a node through its label we can do:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('test_graph', $$
MATCH (u:Person)
RETURN u $$)
as (u agtype);
```

This will return all the nodes in our graph that belong to the `Person` label. Similarly we can filter through a property of a node for example:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('test_graph', $$
MATCH (u:Person) 
WHERE u.name = 'John'
RETURN u $$)
as (u agtype);
```

Here this will return only the nodes that have the property `name` and it equals `'John'`.

Comment: This answer shows an example of using `WHERE` to do some filtering, but does not show using `sum` to aggregate numerical sums which is a key part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example, assume you want to return all users except for those name are `hossam`, then you can do that by the following query:

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.cypher('test', $$ MATCH(n: User) WHERE n.name <> 'hossam' RETURN n$$) as (users agtype) ;
```

this will return all users whose name not equal to `hossam`. You can notice that we applied a filter using the `WHERE` clause which is used for that purpose.

I hope this give you a sense of how you can use filters in age.

Comment: This answer shows an example of using `WHERE` to do some filtering, but does not show using `sum` to aggregate numerical sums which is a key part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your graph along with the required nodes and properties, your postgresql query can be executed this way in Apache AGE

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('your_graph', $$
MATCH (u {year: 2022})
WITH sum(u.sales) as total_sales_2022
ORDER BY u.column_name
RETURN u.column_name, total_sales_2022
$$) AS (column_name agtype, total_sales agtype);
```

You can visit the [AGE docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/cypher.html) to learn more about the WITH, ORDER BY and RETURN clauses in AGE.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *from cypher('sale',$$ MATCH (n:Sales)
WHERE n.year = 2022 OR n.year = 2023
RETURN n.column_name AS column_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN n.year = 2022 THEN n.sales ELSE 0 END) AS total_sales_2022,
       SUM(CASE WHEN n.year = 2023 THEN n.sales ELSE 0 END) AS total_sales_2023
GROUP BY n.column_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2022 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS total_sales_2022,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2023 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS total_sales_2023
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY column_name;
```

In the above query, the CASE statement acts as a replacement for the FILTER clause

Answer (score 0):

We can use the FILTER clause in combination with the aggregate function to achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT column_name,
       SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE year = 2022) AS total_sales_2022,
       SUM(sales) FILTER (WHERE year = 2023) AS total_sales_2023
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY column_name;
```